# *** -[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a very weird memory management issue going on in my apps. I have a UISplitViewController appps in which the RootViewController is a UITabBarApplication. The error:

```
*** -[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x555960
```

always happens when I try to switch views by tapping on the tab bar buttons. I have three tab bar buttons at the button. I also don't have any call to UIImage retain anywhere in my code.

Does anyone have any hints on how to debug this? I have no idea on how to reproduce this specifically, all I know is that this sometimes happens when I switch between tabs.

The debugger breaks at:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"CVore", nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I got Received memory warning. Level=1 and then when I switch tab, it gives me that error.

Comment: Why are you releasing this? [avatar release];

Comment: It's missing some code, actually this is not the issue as I removed all TTImageView and the problem is still there

Comment: Can you post the line where the debugger stop the execution?

Comment: although I think it won't be much help...but I updated my post above.. I've been removing as much UIImage I can find in my apps,but still it's giving me this error.. very weird

Comment: Ok. I would like to help you but it's very hard to know. Do you have any object declared but not initialized like MyObject *object; instead MyObject *object=nil; ? May be your problem is not in an UIImage.

Comment: can that be an issue? Also if the issue is not in UIImage then why does it say UIImage as the error

Comment: Yes, If you don't initialize the var in the right way, in that memory address could be any kind of object. Believe me, I had headaches like this before. I don't telling you that this is the problem. I just share what It happened to me.

Comment: Okay... I'll try to check that as well.. this is very..very painful.. I think I happen to know how to reproduce it.. First.. if the view in the first tab is still loading, I switch to the second tab and switch rapidly between the views.. then this will show up

Comment: I know I can bother you with suggestions what are not useful but I I just want to help but I guess I will confuse you. These are my last suggestions. Are you releasing anything in the viewWillDisappear in your first view contoller? Do you have any memory warning? Are you loading anything through async remote requests that needs a delegate? It's hard to help without the project running.

Comment: If you are really interested to help me (which I really truly appreciate), I can send you the project file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Analyzer](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/snowleopard/static.html) on your code? No guarantee, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Received memory warning. Level=1
```

usually means that your code is leaking memory. From the code you've provided it's impossible to tell what's wrong. Either provide us with more code, or alternatively watch **WWDC 2010 Session 311 - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments** which would help you find errors on your own.

Comment: AFAIK, a memory warning just means that the system is trying to free up some memory for other purposes. It probably does happen when you have a significant leak, but I don't think that the warning necessarily indicates a leak.

Comment: You're right, but judging from the first post I would rather say it'a memory leak. Anyway, I've updated my post. As Charles Barkley says "I may be wrong, but i doubt it" :)

Comment: I've tried running the program in instrument and didn't catch any leaks while this error occured

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're releasing an autoreleased object that you haven't retained. Later, when the autorelease pool is drained/released, a -release message is sent to that (now invalid) object, causing the exception.

A good start would be to [turn on NSZombieEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html) so that you get a better idea of what object is involved. Then take a look at how that object was created in the first place. Since your exception seems to happen when you get a memory warning, look at what happens in that case. You may have a -viewDidUnload method that's incorrectly releasing the object.

Comment: NSZombieEnabled is already on, when it crashes the line in which it breaks doesn't really tell me